# Package 'siunitx' unknown option 'exponent-thresholds'

Tags: siunitx, options

I have been trying to typeset numbers with `siunitx`. I'd like to use the threshold mode, as some numbers don't really require exponents.

So I have been including the package like this:

```
\usepackage[
locale=DE,
range-units=single,
per-mode=power,
exponent-thresholds = -3:3
]{siunitx}
```

When compiling I get this error message:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty:7394: Package keyvalue Error: Unknown option 'exponent-thresholds' for package [  }]
```

It does compile, but the numbers are printed without postprocessing by `siunitx`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,report]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[
locale=DE,
range-units=single,
per-mode=power,
exponent-thresholds = -3:3
]{siunitx}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\SI{10000}{\kilogram} and \SI{10}{\gram\per\cm\tothe{3}}.
\end{document}
```

The log says this about `siunitx`:

```
siunitx.sty    2022-02-02 v3.0.46 A comprehensive (SI) units package
```

Comment: You need a sufficiently-new version for `exponent-thresholds`: add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the resulting info on the version (written into the `.log`) into the question.

Comment: @JosephWright I only recently installed TeXlive on this machine, I assumed I had the most recent version.

Comment: That will depend on how you've installed: if you use for example a Linux system, the 'stock' TeX Live may be significantly out-of-date

Comment: It is indeed, this is how I installed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a more up-to-date `siunitx` to use this option; from the ChangeLog

```
## [v3.2.0] - 2023-01-03

## Added
- Option `exponent-thresholds` and option setting `exponent-mode = threshold`
  to allow selective use of exponent mode output (see issue
  [\#204](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/204))
- Options `print-exponent-implicit-plus` and `print-mantissa-implicit-plus`
  (see issue
  [\#493](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/493))
- Abbreviation `\mF` (see issue
  [\#624](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/624))
- New SI prefixes `\ronna`, `\ronto`, `\quetta` and `\quecto` (see issue
  [\#629](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/629))
```

More generally, you should use options documented for the version you have installed: you can get the appropriate PDF using

```
texdoc siunitx
```

at the Command Prompt/Terminal.